# Rails Activerecord query selective include

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am having trouble optimizing a large activerecord query. I need to include an associated model in my request but due to the size of the return set I only want to include a couple of the associated columns. For example I have:

```
Post.includes(:user).large_set
```

While I am looking for something like:

```
Post.includes(:user.name, :user.profile_pic).large_set
```

I need to actually use the name and profile pic attributes so Post.joins(:user) is not an option as far as I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select` is what you are looking for:

```
Post.select("posts.*, users.name, users.profile_pic").large_set
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I was looking for but you were right that I needed the select method so I'm going to accept this answer. Technically your call includes the entire user model, which is what I was trying to avoid. The smallest call was Post.select("posts.*, users.name, users.profile_pic").large_set

Comment: You are welcome. I updated the answer to match what worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use join to accomplish what you want, as includes does not have this functionality. Or you could white your own includes method :-)